# Azure spatial anchors - Hololens - Not working

Tags: azure, hololens, azure-spatial-anchors

I am using azure spatial anchors samples in my unity project for Hololens 2. I have successfully able to deploy the sample project build to my hololens but when i try to create the anchors it does not do anything, i also have entered the keys.

I dont see any details of anchors created in the admin panel of azure spatial anchors.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give the link of the tutorial you have followed?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

We have recently polished the [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/quickstarts/get-started-unity-hololens?tabs=azure-portal) on how to run the sample.
We have also completely revamped the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/tutorials/tutorial-new-unity-hololens-app?tabs=azure-portal) on implementing your own ASA sample.

Please let us know if you still have any issues running [the sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/quickstarts/get-started-unity-hololens?tabs=azure-portal) by going to the appropriate link on the [support page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/spatial-anchor-support)

Comment: Thanks for your effort but it seems impossible to make it work,